# Input/Output Problem #2

Tags: mathematics

See here for basic rules on problem.

[Input/Output Problem #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75176/input-output-problem-1)

**Problem #2**

Make an optimal machine that accepts any letter combination that begins with a consonant and alternates vowel consonant from then on. ("Y" is considered both vowel and consonant)

Comment: Is mathematics as tag ok? It's more Informatics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my answer :)
Vowel: A,E,I,O,U,Y
Consonant: B,C,D,F,G,H,J,K,L,M,N,P,Q,R,S,T,V,W,X,Y,Z

> [image]

Original Edits:

> [image: answer]

...

> [image: answer]

Comment: I thought of that too, but can an input/output diagram have two ends?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I'm not absolutely sure but I rather think you can have 2 ends :)

Comment: This diagram fails if the string is a single "Y". Should Y be also listed in the consonants? Thanks

Comment: You don't need a point for fail, you just need a Start and any sequence that doesn't end on a red dotted circle fails. Also yes you can have multiple ends.

Comment: @BenFranks a point for fail is not bad :), because I would still be on the red dots

Comment: @Jannis it isn't bad but seen as part of the problem is to optimise it means you have more points than required.

Comment: @BenFranks you better be right, my friend. because most users dont like op's which dont know whats right :)

Comment: @Jannis how can I not know my own puzzle? Yes sequences which do not end on a red dot point are rejected just like sequences that cannot be finished or break one or more of the rules.

Comment: @BenFranks I've updated, so it should be right now

Comment: @Jannis this is optimal if you disregard the fail part which I didn't require.

Comment: It also accepts an empty string, but an empty string does not begin with a consonant.

Comment: how are your two original edits different?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry thanks :) , I've corected it now

Answer (score 5):

Can I have:

> $\oplus\xrightarrow{consonant}\color{red}\bullet\xrightarrow{\;\;vowel\;\;}\color{red}\bullet$
>  $\qquad\qquad\quad\,\mid\qquad\qquad\mid$
>  $\qquad\qquad\quad\,\xleftarrow{\;consonant\;}$

Comment: Not correct if the sequence ends with a vowel.

Comment: @BenFranks; oh right, so is this any better?

Comment: it is correct now but can be optimised. Remember the start can be an end.

Comment: like this? I did move the \oplus to the last red, but this accepts an empty string, which I feel is cheating

Comment: this is correct :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is following since its not specified that if it should end on vowel or consonant.

> [image]

If the failed state is must,

> [image]

If it should alternate and end on consonant then:

> [image]

Comment: It shall alternate ... this is not correct

Comment: @Jannis I have edited my answer please check

Comment: It shall not end on an consonant ... read the question again

Comment: @Jannis where is that in the question?

Comment: Nowhere stands sth about how to end the chain ...

Comment: Doesn't work if the sequence ends on a vowel.

Comment: @BenFranks Edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

My solution has 5 nodes.
(EDIT: I made it too complicated, and a 3-node solution is possible. I'm leaving this answer as-is, because it works and is interesting.)

> [image]
>  Note that the Consonant and Vowel labels in the picture exclude Y, e.g. Vowel means AEIOU only.
>
>  It does not accept an empty string.
>  It accepts a string of Y's.
>  It accepts a string starting with any even number of Y's only if it is followed by a consonant, but not if it is followed by a vowel.
>  It accepts a string starting with any odd number of Y's only if it is followed by a vowel, but not if it is followed by a consonant.
>  The left two nodes of the square deal with any Y prefixes. The right two nodes are used once a non-Y has been seen. I needed the extra starting node in order to disallow an empty string, since the question says the string must begin with a consonant.

Answer (score 0):

Pen-and-paper solution... doop de doo.

> [image]

Comment: Your solution would accept a sequence that begins with a vowel which breaks one of the requirements.

Comment: @BenFranks Rats, you're right...

Answer (score 0):

My attempt:

> I don't know if the "But not Y" part is neccessary, but here goes
>  [image]

Comment: MS Paint lives on!

Answer (score 0):

You can shape it like a triangle. 3 way solution. This assumes what Y is both consonant and vowel, basiclly it cycles between Start and the node O until the rule is broken.

`c       c
      --->    ---> 
Start       O       Fail
      <---    --->
        a      a`