# Input/Output Problem #3

Tags: mathematics

See here for basic rules on problem.

[Input/Output Problem #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75176/input-output-problem-1)

**Problem #3**

Make a machine that accepts sequences of digits from 1-4 that have a product that is a square number.

Comment: can we declare variables?

Comment: What sort of variables are you after?

Comment: boolean, integer

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Yes they are integers.

Comment: I mean declare a variable to check the occurrences of 1, 2, 3, and 4, to see if it should be accepted. Functions like increase a variable by 1 will be in each of the nodes. can we do so?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton The only functions given are in the first problem. You cannot use  "check" functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this works...

> Just keep track that we have an even number of both prime divisors (2 and 3).
>
>  [image]

Comment: damn you were faster than me, I was making a nice graphic ...