# Input/Output Problem #4

Tags: mathematics

See here for basic rules on problem.

[Input/Output Problem #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75176/input-output-problem-1)

**Problem #4**

Make an optimal machine that accepts sequences of digits 1-3 that contain a 1,2,3 in each triple of numbers and has no repeating number. E.g accepts 123123, 132321 but rejects 121323, 123321.

Comment: Why is `121323` rejected?

Comment: Because the first triple "121" does not contain all 3 digits.

Comment: Should 132321 be rejected as 323 does not contain 1?

Comment: Hmm I think it wasn't worded well by me but by triple I mean first 3 numbers then next three numbers following that. Therefore 1st triple is "132" and 2nd triple is "321"

Comment: Then why is 123321 rejected? thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton `33` is repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the solutions being considered optimal are the ones with the fewest numbers of nodes.

Solution using only 8 nodes below (Thrown together quickly on paint, sorry):

> [image: 8 Node Solution]

Comment: This machine allows for 123321 which is rejected by definition of the puzzle.

Comment: Huhn, I just realized it says it rejects 123321 in the examples, but seems to have absolutely no reason as to why it should (And I got answer checkmark), I'll ask OP.

Comment: It says it should have "no repeating number". It looks to me like OP is not in the possession of the right solution. :)

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it just meant no number repeats within a triple, with no absolutely no regard from one triple to another

Answer (score 5):

## Answer

Optimized I/O machine

> [image: I/O machine]

## Non-optimized version

I think this should work for the I/O machine

> [image: Input/Output]

Comment: I think this needs an additional arrow with 2 from the middle red dot straight left.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje Then you would have a repeating set of 2s, for example 1322..., which is rejected by definition of the puzzle.

Comment: Don't think so. What happens if you're in the middle red dot state and a 2 appears? That is not valid anymore? You're at the end of a triplet so any new valid triplet should lead you to a new end state. What happens if the first new value is a 2? It should go to the same location as a startin ginput of 2. Wait sorry, I overlooked the repeating digit constraint.

Comment: Can you see a way to optimise this more.

Comment: Wouldn't an empty input be valid too? In that case the start node should also be red.