# Input/Output Problem #6

Tags: mathematics

See here for basic rules on problem.

[Input/Output Problem #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75176/input-output-problem-1)

**Problem #6**

Make an optimal machine that accepts sequences of integer digits 1-4 such that all 1s are at the beginning and all 4s are at the end. Also there has to be exactly one of either the 2 or the 3 with any number of the other in each sequence. There doesn't have to be any 1s or 4s.

You do not need a route for failed sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer uses 6 nodes.

> [image]
>  I forgot to mark the left-most node as the start node, but that should be obvious.
>  One branch produces one 2 with any number of 3s on either side. The other branch does the same for one 3 with any number of 2s either side.

Comment: Scherphius +1 nice answer I believe this is optimal.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

This should be the optimized version. I added some colored boxes which don't belong to the machine to subdivide its parts

> [image: Input/Output]

## Previous Answers

pre edit: "Also there has to be exactly one of either the 2 or the 3."

> [image: Input/Output]

post edit: "Also there has to be exactly one of either the 2 or the 3 with any number of the other in each sequence."

non-optimized:

> [image: Input/Output_2]

not using empty paths

> [image: Input/Output]

Comment: This solution doesn't accept answers with zero 2 or 3s or more than one 2 or 3s.

Comment: @BenFranks "Also there has to be exactly one of either the 2 or the 3." But that's the point of the machine?

Comment: I think he means there either has to be exactly one 2 with any number of 3s around it, or exactly one 3 with any number of 2s around it.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis That is what I was trying to say. I will reword the puzzle to reflect this clearer.

Comment: Your new solution has two arrows marked 2 and two arrows marked 3 leaving the start node. How do I know which one I should take?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis That is allowed, as seen in example C in Puzzle #1.

Comment: @beemaad solution is valid but not optimised.

Comment: I see. So these machines are really only for generating sequences, and can not necessarily be used for verifying whether an existing sequence is valid. Fair enough.

Comment: @beemaad I think you are forgetting a function you are allowed to use which would it more optimal.

Comment: @BenFranks of course - this makes it a lot easier... working a little too fast on this^^