# Input/Output Problem #7

Tags: mathematics

See here for basic rules on problem.

[Input/Output Problem #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75176/input-output-problem-1)

**Problem #7**

Make an optimal machine that accepts sequences of integer digits 1-4 such that each triplet contains three different numbers. Accepted examples; 123124234, 231123. Rejected example; 122341

You do not need a route for failed sequences.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. Can you please tell the source of these 'puzzles'? Are these your homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think beemaad's solution is optimal if the solution has to be [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). However, since the rules state that we can have multiple possible transitions from a given state for the same input, we can get this one down to 9 states.

> [image]

Comment: Looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Was what I was looking for +1

Answer (score 5):

Assuming, the empty sequence gets accepted, this should work:

> The machine can be simplified by accumulating the sequences 12 and 21, 13 and 31, etc. 
>  [image: Input/Output]

Comment: Nice answer +1.

Comment: You're really into this beemaad :)

Comment: Can you optimise this further?