# Problem #NaN Fodder/Output

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, visual

> Inspired by Ben Franks' [Input/Output Problem #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/75176) and the others in the series

[image: NaN Fodder/Output]

Hint: Knowledge required is

> a pop culture reference going back almost 50 years, but still fairly well-known

Comment: Are the connecting symbols being used from any kind of standard?

Comment: @feelinferrety no, not that I am aware of.